nvidia nsight compute tool crashes when run as root
I am trying to profile a program that uses CUDA on Alma Linux 9. I've installed Nvidia's nsight compute tool and when I start to try and profile my program, I get an error:
==ERROR== ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM - The user does not have permission to access NVIDIA GPU Performance Counters on the target device 0. For instructions on enabling permissions and to get more information see https://developer.nvidia.com/ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM

When I try running the program as root though, I get another error:
################# ERROR: CrashReporter #################
CrashReporter

Qt initialization failed

Failed to load Qt platform plugin: "xcb"
 - Library path: /usr/local/NVIDIA-Nsight-Compute-2024.3/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/Plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
Application is going to abort
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :10.0
/usr/local/NVIDIA-Nsight-Compute-2024.3/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/ncu-ui: line 26: 2032536 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$NV_AGORA_PATH/CrashReporter" "NVIDIA Nsight Compute" "NVIDIA Nsight Compute" "2024.3.2.0 (build 34861637) (public-release)" "$NV_AGORA_PATH/ncu-ui.bin" "$@"

That library is there, however I am using xrdp to access the machine, could that be why this failure happens?

Hey, the website linked to explains exactly what you should do, and that does not entail running the program as root.

Sorry, what link?

first error message in your post!
